# Count points in a polygon that changes form ("on the fly calculation")

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, point-in-polygon

I have tried to find a plugin for this, with no luck.
Perhaps someone knows of a plugin that can do the following:

In this project I create a lot of polygons that contain points, and the size of the polygons is dependent of how many points there are inside the polygon. Therefore I need to manually change the size of the polygons to get a certain number of points inside it.

It is tedious work to run a new "Points in polygon" command as soon as I have changed a polygon and want to know the number of points. Is there any way to get this calculations directly on screen some how (a sort of "on the fly" point calculation)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a plugin, but a nice solution using Spatialite and triggers.

If you put both your polygons and points layers into a Spatialite DB, then you can add a trigger to the polygon table to update the "point_count" column on each update of the polygons.
Here's the trigger statement (I called the polygon layer "areas" and the point count column "cnt_pts"):

```
CREATE TRIGGER "areas_update_cnt" AFTER UPDATE ON "areas"
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    UPDATE areas SET cnt_pts = (SELECT count(*)
    FROM points 
    WHERE ST_Within(points.geometry, areas.geometry));
END
```

Now in QGIS load both layers from Spatialite and set labeling on the polygon layer to use the cnt_pts column. Each time you edit the polygons *and* save changes, the labels (=cnt_pts) will update with the current count of points in each polygon.

Comment: Thanks. Butmy SQL knowledge is a bit rusty, and I don't get the trigger to work. Below is my code and the error message:

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER "fiber_areas_update_cnt" AFTER UPDATE ON "fiber_areas" 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
UPDATE fiber_areas SET count = (SELECT count(*) 
FROM byggnader_city 
WHERE ST_Within(byggnader_city.geometry, fiber_areas.geometry)); 
END

Comment: SQLite error: no such column: byggnader_city.geometry

Comment: You need to import the layers into a **Spatialite** database, and do the trigger there. I recommend [spatialite-gui](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/spatialite_gui/index) for this.